# Some confusion regarding defining factor variables

Tags: r, regression, data-science, dummy-variable

When defining factor variables in R I have defined them as such up till now:

```
q5_data$high <- ifelse(q5_data$totexp >median(q5_data$totexp),1,0)
```

However I noticed people using things such as:

```
factor(directions, levels= c("North", "East", "South", "West"))
```

Do I have to define a factor variable explicitly as a factor variable or will simply having a vector of 1's and 0's work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is in fact two questions.

### 1.

In R, the creation of dummy variables is seldom, if ever, needed. R's modelling functions take care of that automatically. But if you want to dichotomise a numeric variable, in the question's example as values below or above the median, `ifelse` is just one of the ways of doing it.

Here are other two (essentially the same way). They take advantage of the fact that `FALSE/TRUE` are coded as the integers `0/1` and coerce the logical values to a numeric class.

```
set.seed(2021)
x <- runif(10, 0, 100)

y <- ifelse(x > median(x), 1, 0)
z <- as.integer(x > median(x))
identical(y, z)
#[1] FALSE
```

The result is `FALSE` because though the values are equal the objects' classes are not.

```
class(y)
#[1] "numeric"
class(z)
#[1] "integer"
```

The solution would not to care about that unless an `identical` result is needed.

```
z2 <- as.numeric(x > median(x))
identical(y, z2)
#[1] TRUE
```

To see why this is probably not needed, the regression functions will called it their own, run the following. Output omitted.

```
model.matrix(~ x > median(x))
```

---

### 2.

A different problem is to bin the data. If you want to create a factor of small, medium and large out of a numeric variable, functions like [`cut`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.html), [`.bincode`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bincode.html) or [`findInterval`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html) can be of use.

```
i <- findInterval(x, c(0, 33.33, 66.67, Inf))
levels <- c("Small", "Medium", "Large")
f <- factor(levels[i], levels = levels)

f
# [1] Medium Large  Large  Medium Medium Large  Medium Small  Large 
#[10] Large 
#Levels: Small Medium Large
```

Why have I explicitly set the factor levels? Because R will default to the lexicographic order, and `"Large"` is the first, then `"Medium"` and `"Small"` would have been assigned to the greatest values. To assign factor levels manually gives full control on the result.